# Child Node attributes changes after store.put in IE8 only

Tags: javascript, dom, internet-explorer-8, dojo

I am using dojo 1.9.

**Functionality:**
I am populating data in observable dgrid store based on continuous polling call.
There is a functionality of expansion of row, in which some data( termed as child node) is appended to node created after of store.put().

We are creating this child node on click on "+" sign button used for expansion and store that in one global variable for JS.
eg. this.childNode[var1] = tempNode;

After every polling call we populate main row using store.put(mainRow).

Then we fetch mainNode =>mainNode = dom.byId(mainRow).

After fetching mainNode we append child node if that row is expanded. => mainNode.appendChild(this.childNode[var1]); where var1 is parameter.

In all browsers this functinality is working fine. Only in case of Internet Explorer 8 after store.put attributes of child Node like innerHTML/childnodes get blank which is breaking expansion in case of polling call.

*Please let me know in case anyone has come across this issue. Also please suggest some solution/approach for this issue?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like IE8 did not have native capability to handle the code. I have added http://modernizr.com/ JS library and got this to work.